# Is it possible to subclass Lock() objects in Python? If not, other ways to debug deadlock?

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, thread-safety, deadlock

So, I've got a multithreaded python program, which is currently suffering from deadlock. I was going to log lock acquiring by subclassing threading.Lock objects:

```
import traceback
class DebugLock(threading.Lock):
    def acquire(self):
        print >>sys.stderr, "acquired", self
        #traceback.print_tb
        threading.Lock.acquire(self)  
    def release(self):
        print >>sys.stderr, "released", self
        #traceback.print_tb
        threading.Lock.release(self)
```

When I try to run the program, I get the following error:

```
    class DebugLock(threading.Lock):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    cannot create 'builtin_function_or_method' instances
```

So, my question is twofold:

1. Is it possible to subclass Lock objects to do what I'm doing?
2. If not, what is the best way to debug deadlock in python?

Note: I'm not writing any Python extension. There's a similar question: [How to debug deadlock with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527296/how-to-debug-deadlock-with-python)
However, it deals with compiling C++ code and using GDB, which I can't do since my code is pure python.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could just use the "has a lock" versus "is a lock" approach, like so:

```
import threading, traceback, sys
class DebugLock(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
    def acquire(self):
        print("acquired", self)
        #traceback.print_tb
        self._lock.acquire()
    def release(self):
        print("released", self)
        #traceback.print_tb
        self._lock.release()
    def __enter__(self):
        self.acquire()
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.release()
```

where I've thrown in the appropriate context guards since you likely want to use the `with` syntax with your locks (who wouldn't?).

Usage shown below:

```
    >>> lock = DebugLock()
    >>> with lock:
    ...     print("I'm atomic!")
    ... 
    acquired <__main__.DebugLock object at 0x7f8590e50190>
    I'm atomic!
    released <__main__.DebugLock object at 0x7f8590e50190>
    >>>
```

Answer (score 5):

Russ answered the important question (#2), I'll answer question #1.

Doesn't appear to be possible.  threading.Lock() is a factory function ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Lock)).  It calls thread.allocate_lock() - there's no control over Lock object creation.  You also cannot monkeypatch the thread.LockType class definition (the class skeleton exposed in thread.pi).

```
>>> thread.LockType.foo = "blah"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'thread.lock'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do something like inheritance without running into this error, I suggest you try

```
 import traceback
 from threading import Lock
 class DebugLock():
     def __init__(self,lock = None):
         self.lock = lock or Lock()

         # normally done with __dict__
         for command in dir(self.lock):
             self.__dict__[command] = getattr(self.lock,command)
```

My normal method of using `self.__dict__.update(lock.__dict__)` doesn't seem to be working. I tested this out with the locking code

```
 X = DebugLock()
 y = X.lock
 Y = DebugLock(y)
 X.acquire()
 Y.acquire()
 X.release()
 Y.release()
```

and that hangs, so I think it is working.